# Insert to a table column based on php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a comboBox that has options: transpo, meal and medical. I want to insert the values into the column that corresponds to option that the user chooses. 
Is it possible?

This is my latest query.

```
 $conn->query("INSERT INTO expenses
    SET employee_id = :emp_id,
    client_id = :client_id,
    CASE
      WHEN :cat == 'transpo' THEN transpo_exp = :worth
      WHEN :cat == 'meal' THEN meal_exp = :worth
      WHEN :cat == 'medical' THEN medical_exp = :worth");
```

Comment: you can't use **set** while inserting data. It can be use only in updating record.

Comment: @JaiminVyas Nope it is  valid for `INSERT` also see docs

Answer (score 0):

```
 please use array [] symbol in select name.

  <select name="expenses[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>     

  and get array variable.

  $expenses= $_POST['expenses'];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($expenses); $i++){
        echo $expenses[$i];
        $Qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO expenses VALUES('$expenses[$i]]')"); 
    }
```